# AchartEngine getScreenPosition to Display Toast near the user click point

Tags: android, achartengine, toast

[image]hello I want to display a toast when user click on achartengine Point with display value . I am trying to get screen position value using toScreenPoint method but it will give wrong value if I pan a screen (move a chart) after that it give proper screen point and I set  this Value to Toast. my code is shown below.

```
       chart=new TimeChart(dataset, charthelper.getXYMultipleSeriesRenderer());
           graphview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SeriesSelection ss=graphview.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
              if (ss == null) {
                  } else {

                double[] screenPoint = chart.toScreenPoint(new double[] {
                        ss.getXValue(),ss.getValue() },0);
                toast_textview.setText(ss.getValue()+"");
                Toast toast=new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, (int)screenPoint[0],(int)screenPoint[1]);
                toast.setView(toast_layout);
                toast.show();       
                  }
                }
    });
    container_layout.addView(graphview,0);
```

**[UPDATE]**
 i solved it using this way

```
 /**
     * set ontouch listener for double tap
     */
    graphview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            detector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    graphview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SeriesSelection ss = graphview.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
            if (ss == null) {
            } else {
                /**
                 * toast display only series of value which index is
                 * zero
                 */
                if (ss.getSeriesIndex() == 0) {
                    toast_textview.setText(ss.getValue() + "");
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                    toast_textview.setText(formatter.format(ss.getValue()) + "");
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, (int) x,
                            (int) y);
                    toast.setView(toast_layout);
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you ever find and answer?

Comment: still i didn't get accurate point value but right now i am using touchevent event.getX() and event.getY()

Comment: I cannot even get SeriesSelection to not be null. Do you have more of how you defined the chart and everything to see if your doing it different than me.

Comment: see my Update @jcaruso and "I cannot even get SeriesSelection to not be null". means i can't understand

Comment: it's object of GestureDetector.
detector = new GestureDetector(Tempo_Graph.this, listener);

Comment: @jcaruso i am using 
GraphicalView graphview = new GraphicalView(Tempo_Graph.this, chart);

instead of ChartFactory.this may help you to get null value from getCurrentSeriesAndPoint().